# Converting alphanumeric value in Java Long type

Tags: java

I am requesting **Salesforce** webservice to create Lead in Salesforce from Java application. The response of service is 18 digit alphanumeric value as the lead I'd. Want to save this id in local database.
But my Lead Entity is having "`leadId`" field as Long type and this fields is being used by other applications flow also. Means that I can't Change its type.

Column is

```
@Column(name=orderid)
    Long leadId
```

What are the ways to save that alphanumeric value in this field.

Comment: `Long.parseLong(alphaNumeric)`?

Comment: You can convert character to numeric value using Character.getNumericValue(c) but there is no any library to do in the String level unless you write your own hash algorithm or function to map alpha numeric to long values.

Comment: @cricket_007 I think it will throw numberFormateException

Comment: There is also Long.parseLong("Hazelnut", 36) Look - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Well, we can't see your field, so how would we know? Did you try to remove the non-number characters?

Comment: @PrabinPaudel That might throw an exception as well, since the string is 18 characters long, the value in base 10 can be greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.